# Why is this while function not working: Python

Tags: python

I want to make a loop where today's date goes down until it matches an earlier date. Here is my code:

```
from datetime import date
Months = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"]
today = date.today()

A= ("%s %s" % (Months[today.month - 1],today.day))
end_date= "December 1"


while A != end_date:
    a=today.day
    a=a-1
    A= ("%s %s" % (Months[today.month - 1],a))
    print(A)
```

Why does my loop get stuck in December 9 if I specified in the loop "a" to diminish until "A" is equal to "end_date"?

Comment: Because you redefine `a` in each iteration. Move `a = today.day` out of the loop

Comment: First line of the loop is buggy.

Comment: Every iteration, your a variable gets today's day in the first line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a=today.day
```

needs to be outside the loop:

```
from datetime import date
Months = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"]
today = date.today()

A= ("%s %s" % (Months[today.month - 1],today.day))
end_date= "December 1"

a=today.day
while A != end_date:
    #a=today.day
    a=a-1
    A= ("%s %s" % (Months[today.month - 1],a))
    print(A)
```

you were setting the a to be the current day - 1, every time the loop ran, so it would never decrement.